# Generate questions based on keyword in php

Tags: php, artificial-intelligence

I am working on a project that must generate human readable questions based on a single keyword. I'm kind of lost on how to start though. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: Ok so for example, I have a site where it pulls information from web services. It then takes keywords that these services provides and then building questions dynamically. So for example if it provides a keyword of president it might generate a question such as "is the president doing a good job?". The only thing I can think of is having template questions that these keywords get plugged into but I was hoping there was a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A computer is no different from a human in this regard.  If you ask a human to come up with random questions about "president", he or she will draw upon past experience and knowledge to formulate questions.  For example, the question "Is the president doing a good job?" will probably be the first one produced, because in the past experiences of most people, it has been an interesting question about the keyword provided.

So you're basically walking into a very complex area of study.  This is going to involve probably thousands of question templates, a neural net of some kind to select questions based on input, and a lot of trial-and-error.

In short, this isn't something you can just throw together in a few hours and be done with it.

Comment: That's what I thought but thought maybe there was another way. I'll start working on it then lol thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could take a large text pool (maybe spidered pages from the web) and calculate how often two words are seen together. You will get a weighted graph in which you can start at your keyword and walk away from it.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to have humans generate your questions - crowd source it. I would create two pages. The first randomly shows one of your keywords and asks the user to input a question about the keyword that interests them. These user inputed questions are saved in a database.

The second page would simply show the most popular questions from individual keywords.

The tricky part would be tallying the questions. You could brute force it by stripping all punctuation, lowercasing, and possibly even ordering the words of the question alphabetically ( or you could use a neural network like ANN to test whether two inputted questions are the same).